# What's the best way to mock a .net service reference, like Amazon's web services

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, service-reference

I've generated some service references to Amazon, and I was wondering if there was a good, quick way to generate mocks against the whole thing, or I instead I have to implement a mock binding, and do it that way

Answer (score 2):

You cannot easily mock a .NET service reference client class. You could use the service contract interface in your code and mock this one.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [MockingBird](http://mockingbird.codeplex.com/) framework.

*Disclaimer: I havn't used it myself so I don't know if it serves your need.*